# Spring Integration Ftp remoteFileTemplate got stuck on getting file from ftp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration

When using RemoteFileTemplate to get 20k files from FTP, always 15 or 20 files got stuck and after 10 minutes FTP return error code:

- FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
- Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245:
  425

FTP server config:

- MaxInstances 2000 (Limits the overall number of connections)
- MaxClients   1000 (Limits the number of connections on a
  per-server/vhost basis)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>rabbitmq.listener</groupId>
    <artifactId>listener</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ftp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.type=direct
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.default-requeue-rejected=false
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.consumers-per-queue=5
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.prefetch=5
```

DemoConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableRabbit
public class DemoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DirectMessageListenerContainer container(final DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory) {
        final DirectMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = containerFactory.createListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setQueueNames("in_queue"); // has 20.000 messages before starting this application
        listenerContainer.setListenerId("listener_in_queue");
        return listenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory() {
        final DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost("ftp.test.com");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(1021);
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername("test");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword("test");
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(defaultFtpSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteFileTemplate<FTPFile> ftpFileRemoteFileTemplate(final SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory) {
        return new RemoteFileTemplate<>(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow demoFlow(final DirectMessageListenerContainer container, final RemoteFileTemplate<FTPFile> ftpFileRemoteFileTemplate) {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(container))
                .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    final String file = payload.toString();
                    ftpFileRemoteFileTemplate.get(file, stream -> {
                        try {
                            log.info("{}: {}", file, IOUtils.toString(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length());
                        } finally {
                            stream.close();
                        }
                    });
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }

}
```

log file

```
2019-01-28 13:37:32.208  WARN 2688 --- [pool-1-thread-14                        ] org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession                                               : failed to disconnect FTPClient

org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:388)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:732)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1853)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.finalizeRaw(FtpSession.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.close(FtpSession.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.close(CachingSessionFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:456)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.get(RemoteFileTemplate.java:393)
        at rabbitmq.listener.DemoConfiguration.lambda$demoFlow$1(DemoConfiguration.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:237)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:204)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-01-28 13:37:32.208  WARN 2688 --- [pool-1-thread-14                        ] org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession                                               : failed to disconnect FTPClient

org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:388)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(FTP.java:300)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.getReply(FTP.java:732)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.completePendingCommand(FTPClient.java:1853)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.finalizeRaw(FtpSession.java:108)
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.close(FtpSession.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.close(CachingSessionFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:456)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.get(RemoteFileTemplate.java:393)
        at rabbitmq.listener.DemoConfiguration.lambda$demoFlow$1(DemoConfiguration.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:237)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:204)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2019-01-28 13:37:32.212  WARN 2688 --- [pool-1-thread-14                        ] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler                            : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1613)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1517)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:237)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:204)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:451)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.get(RemoteFileTemplate.java:393)
        at rabbitmq.listener.DemoConfiguration.lambda$demoFlow$1(DemoConfiguration.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:102)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.readRaw(FtpSession.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.readRaw(CachingSessionFactory.java:280)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$get$4(RemoteFileTemplate.java:396)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:442)
        ... 36 common frames omitted

2019-01-28 13:37:32.215 ERROR 2688 --- [pool-1-thread-14                        ] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer                              : Failed to invoke listener

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1613)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1517)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.callExecuteListener(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer$SimpleConsumer.handleDelivery(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:955)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:111)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:237)
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:204)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:451)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.get(RemoteFileTemplate.java:393)
        at rabbitmq.listener.DemoConfiguration.lambda$demoFlow$1(DemoConfiguration.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:102)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain InputStream for remote file /test/test_file_1245: 425
        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.readRaw(FtpSession.java:98)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.readRaw(CachingSessionFactory.java:280)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.lambda$get$4(RemoteFileTemplate.java:396)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:442)
        ... 36 common frames omitted
```

-- EDIT

I replaced `CachingSessionFactory` with `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` to avoid pool issues and got same behavior. 10 messages were in `unacked` state on RabbitMQ for 10 minutes. After 10 minutes, I could see that files were processed and there were no more messages on RabbitMQ. I could see that on ftp server one session was in IDLE status for 10 minutes.

```
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory() {
        final DefaultFtpSessionFactory defaultFtpSessionFactory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setClientMode(FTPClient.PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE);
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setHost("ftp.test.com");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPort(1021);
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setUsername("test");
        defaultFtpSessionFactory.setPassword("test");
        return defaultFtpSessionFactory;
    }
```

This does not seem like pool or FTP 421 problem to me, it is most likely something in the `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` or session itself? Why are these threads hanging for so long?

Comment: How does it work with the `FTPClient.ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE`?

Comment: When ACTIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE is set all threads are stuck. Ftp server log is empty.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes `421: Service not available, closing control connection. This may be a reply to any command if the service knows it must shut down.`

Answer (score 0):

The `CachingSessionFactory` doesn't have a limit by default:

```
/**
 * Create a CachingSessionFactory with the specified session limit. By default, if
 * no sessions are available in the cache, and the size limit has been reached,
 * calling threads will block until a session is available.
 * <p>
 * Do not cache a {@link DelegatingSessionFactory}, cache each delegate therein instead.
 * @see #setSessionWaitTimeout(long)
 * @see #setPoolSize(int)
 *
 * @param sessionFactory The underlying session factory.
 * @param sessionCacheSize The maximum cache size.
 */
public CachingSessionFactory(SessionFactory<F> sessionFactory, int sessionCacheSize) {
```

and we end up with this configuration in the underlying `SimplePool`:

```
/**
 * Creates a SimplePool with a specific limit.
 * @param poolSize The maximum number of items the pool supports.
 * @param callback A {@link PoolItemCallback} implementation called during various
 * pool operations.
 */
public SimplePool(int poolSize, PoolItemCallback<T> callback) {
    if (poolSize <= 0) {
        this.poolSize.set(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        this.targetPoolSize.set(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        this.permits.release(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    else {
        this.poolSize.set(poolSize);
        this.targetPoolSize.set(poolSize);
        this.permits.release(poolSize);
    }
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

So, consider to have a reasonable cache size for your `CachingSessionFactory`.

Comment: Please check my EDIT on main description. Replaced `CachingSessionFactory`  with `DefaultFtpSessionFactory` (without poll size) but I got the same behavior.